# Initializing java.awt.Robot within systemd in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: xorg, java, 17.10, systemd, wayland

I have a service that can capture the screen of a particular user using `java.awt.Robot` APIs while running as root (as it does several other things than capturing user screen).

The environment to initialize `java.awt.Robot` is set in the service file `/lib/systemd/system/screencap.service` using the Environment variables - `$XAUTHORITY` and `$DISPLAY` of the particular user.

```
[Unit]
Description=My Screen Capture Service (running as root)
After=syslog.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Environment="XAUTHORITY=/home/myuser/.Xauthority" "DISPLAY=:0"
WorkingDirectory=/usr/share/java/screencap
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar /usr/share/java/screencap/screencap.jar
SuccessExitStatus=143
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=screencap
PrivateTmp=true
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

**It works for all distros except Ubuntu 17.10 because it uses wayland instead of x11.**

When I execute `java -jar /usr/share/java/screencap/screencap.jar` from user terminal, `new Robot()` is able to find the GUI context on Ubuntu 17.10 and runs perfectly.

I do not know what should be the value of `Environment="XAUTHORITY=/home/myuser/.Xauthority" "DISPLAY=:0"` for Ubuntu 17.10. It cannot be `XAUTHORITY=` because `$XAUTHORITY` is undefined in Ubuntu 17.10. **Where can I find the wayland equivalent of this?**

I have already tried
`Environment="XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland" "DISPLAY=:0"` and
`Environment="WAYLAND_DISPLAY=wayland-0" "DISPLAY=:0"`
but neither of them works.

EDIT: I cannot enforce my users to switch back to X11/XORG. I want my service to work in wayland.

Comment: I cannot enforce the user to switch to Xorg. I want my service to work in wayland as it is.

Comment: I retracted my comment, so it's back to normal.